# TileStache blank preview with MBtiles

Tags: mbtiles, tilestache

I am trying to host a mbtiles on TileStache, but the preview page always shows a blank page. The config file is like this

```
{
  "cache": {
    "name": "Test",
    "path": "/tmp/stache",
    "umask": "0000"
  },
  "layers": {
    "osm_layer": {
      "provider": {
        "name": "proxy",
        "url": "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png"
      }
    },
    "mbtiles_layer": {
      "provider": {
        "name": "mbtiles",
        "tileset": "rhodeisland.mbtiles"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The message from the server is like that

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/preview.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/preview.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/163/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/164/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/165/394.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/396.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/0/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:27] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:35] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:35] "GET /mbtiles_layer/10/162/395.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/2/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/3/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2022 12:26:43] "GET /mbtiles_layer/2/1/1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Can anyone helps? I'm a newbie to this area and I think I have tried everything I found on the internet but it still shows a blank preview.